# EclipseLink Sequence generator does not start from initial value provided

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

PFB my code,

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="empIdSequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="empIdSequence",initialValue=10000,allocationSize=1)
    private Integer empId;
```

I am using EclipseLink 2.5.x implementation and MySQL Database. When i create a record the empId starts from 1 instead of 10000. Is there any other configuration that i need to do ?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent conflicts everytime you restart your application or spin up a new instance somewhere, the intialValue is only used when creating the sequence generator in the database, when the tables are dropped and created.